# Installing Flutter SDK 1.22.5-stable fails early in the process

Tags: windows, flutter, failed-installation

I’m getting trouble installing flutter on Windows 10 (windows SDK 1.22.5-stable) for the first time. I tried many times following the instructions given here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows.

I also tried with the previous SDK (1.22.4-stable). I was able to get further in the installation process but still, the installation process is not going as expected.
So, I’m asking for help for the most up to date SDK 1.22.5-stable.
I have downloaded the windows SDK (1.22.5-stable) zip file and extracted it under my « Documents » folder. I did update my path. When I run flutter doctor, from the power shell, I’m getting this:

[image: Powershell 1]

…followed by…

[image: Powershell 2]

I search forums about this and did not find a solution. I saw people suggesting deleting the bin\cache\ folder and retry flutter doctor. But before doing so I have noted that the cache folder was containing the dart-sdk folder but it was empty (I’m not sure that is normal).

So I have deleted the cache folder and ran flutter doctor again. I got the same result.
Next I tried to run flutter doctor again without deleting the cache folder. This time I got this:

[image: Powershell 3]

I don’t know what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but some info that might help. If you check you will notice that flutter ver 1.22.4 is 660+ Mb while version 1.22.5 is only 127 Mb and that is a huge difference. Personally I have a problem with the internet connection which breaks constantly and to update my flutter version I always download the full SDK and unzip it after deleting the previous version. Upgrading via the command "flutter upgrade" always failed because my breaking connection. Hence downloading the full sdk has served me well over the years until version 1.22.5. I suspect that the earlier versions included the full Dart SDK and unzipping the flutter file provided all the requirements in terms of getting both flutter and its compatible version of Dart. Now it seems that flutter file include only the flutter SDK and by running the flutter command it will download the required Dart SDK (as per the information on the flutter installation page).
Currently I am staying with version 1.22.4 and preparing to have separate installation for both flutter and dart that will allow me to download each file separately, unzip them in their respective folders and hope that they work without any problems.
Your first two images indicate that your flutter version 1.22.5 seems to be doing its work OK and have successfully downloaded the dart sdk zip file. The problem was at the unzipping of the downloaded file. My guess would be that you need to install Git (recent releases) as they include an unzipper. Just follow the standard installation of Git for windows and its recommended options and then try running flutter command again from version 1.22.5.